# Rails query with has_many relation in a list of [types, ids]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have models with variables (many model classes : polymorphic relation), and constraints between variables (variables are not necessarily in the same model).

I try to make a query to find all constraints associated to a list of models (with all vars associated to the models in list), and I really don't know how to do it.

My models looks like this.

```
class Model1 < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vars, as: :model
end
class Model2 < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vars, as: :model
end

class Var < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model, polymorphic: true
  # model_type and model_id in vars table
  has_many :cns_vars
  has_many :constraints, through: :cns_vars
end

class_CnsVar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :var
  belongs_to :constraint
end

class Constraint < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cns_vars
  has_many :vars, through: :cns_vars
end
```

To find constraints related to one model I have this query :

```
Constraint.includes(:vars).where(active: true, vars: {model_id: model.id, model_type: model.class.to_s})
```

This query give me the constraints that have at least one var associated to my model.
I need constraints with **all vars** associated to a list of models.

Is there a way to make the same query, but with all vars associated to the model ?
Is there a way to make the same query, but with all vars associated to a list of models ?

```
Constraint.includes(:vars).where(active: true, vars: {*[var.model_type, var.model_id] in my models list*})
```

Is there a solution to do this with one query ?
Or do I have to do it another way ?

Thanks for your help.

(ruby : 2.6.0 / rails : 5.2.3)

EDIT :
To give better explanation, look at this function that returns what I need, but this make too much queries !

```
def constraints_for_models_list(models)
  all_vars = models.flat_map(&:vars)

  all_constraints = all_vars.flat_map(&:constraints)
  all_constraints.uniq!

  constraints = []
  all_constraints.each do |constraint|
    next unless constraint.vars.included_in?(all_vars)

    constraints << constraint
  end

  return constraints
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Constraint.includes(:vars).where(active: true).where.not(vars: { model: nil })`
of course if I correctly get the point of what you're trying.

for what you asked in comment:
`Constraint.includes(:vars).where(active: true).where('vars.model_type IN 
 ?', ['Model1',Model2'])`

Comment: or if you whant to parametrize scope:
`(model_types)-> { includes(:vars).where(active: true, vars: { model: { type: model_types } })`

Comment: All vars are associated to a model (there is no var with model: nil). Il want vars with model in a apecific list of models.

Comment: so look at comment above

Comment: I do not search constraints attached to a specific type of model, but to a model list (this list includes diffrents models types).

Comment: My list of models doesn't include all models of certain types...
model_type is the class name for the polymorphic relation.